# How can I cancel a ProgressBar?

Tags: android, android-layout, progress-bar

So, I have switched to using a `ProgressBar` from `ProgressDialog` and I don't find now any method to make the `ProgressBar` cancellable meaning if I click anywhere outside the `ProgressBar`'s view area, it will dismiss and also I want to attach a listener to it so that I am able to execute some code when it does get canceled.

This `ProgressBar` is the simplest, indeterminate, non-customized one, I have:

```
<ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/search_tutors_progress_bar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:visibility="gone"/>
```

How can I achieve the above?

Answer (score 2):

You use a ProgressBar only to represent the progress of something, it doesn't hold any logic nor make any kind of process, it only gets updated (if you want to) by an external process (like an AsyncTask, for example). That's why it doesn't have any listeners and it's not cancellable, because the ProgressBar only sits in there so another process has the option to update it or set its visibility to GONE when it's finished.

So basically, you shouldn't worry about the progress bar itself, you should worry about the process that the progress bar is representing and how and when this process can get cancelled, so you can call progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE) when this happens.

Just as an example, I use a ProgressBar to represent the loading of an ImageView with Picasso. Picasso offers a callback to let you know when the loading succeded or failed. In both cases, I set my ProgressBar visibility to GONE and take other actions depending the case. That's why I say you have to know how and when you should manipulate your ProgressBar visibility.

```
Picasso.with(this)
                .load("https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w640" + m.getPosterPath())
                .into(posterImageView, new com.squareup.picasso.Callback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess() {
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError() {
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        noImageFoundTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
});
```

---

OK, so if your concern is about UX and you want to make a ProgressBar dismissable by the user, you can implement this kind of workaround:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp">
        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/dismissButton"
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:background="@android:drawable/ic_menu_close_clear_cancel"
            android:layout_gravity="center"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

The imageview will handle the dismiss of the progressbar.

```
dismissButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            dismissButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            //Take other actions on dismiss
        }
});
```

[image]

Comment: Then, what if loading images tell took considerably longer in an atypical case(slow N/W) and your user, feeling a bit annoyed by this wait, tried tapping outside the progress bar to "dismiss" it? The happy scenario would ideally be, dismissal of the bar and optionally show a message. With ProgressDialog, I had the cancellation handled well through dismiss listener. What you have posted(view visibility) is what I already have but I wanted to take care of UX nuances.

Comment: Check my latest edit, I don't know if that'll suit what you're looking for.

Comment: +1 Well, I didn't go for this finally but this is pretty decent what you have suggested. Might go for exactly this in some other layout. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your ProgressBar sits in some layout e.g. a LinearLayout. You could create an OnTouchListener and apply it to the layout which contains your ProgressBar, apply the same OnTouchListener to any other Views which are visible. You can dismiss the ProgressBar and execute other code from within the OnTouchListener.

Answer (score 0):

At top most(Parent)layout.Apply OnTouchListener ,and put this line

```
progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```